# Finding directories with different ownership using find

Tags: bash

I'm having trouble testing directory ownership using find. I believe this is due to being in a sub process but I'm not sure.

```
#!/bin/bash

EXAMPLE_DIR_OWNER="testuser:testgroup"
EXAMPLE_DIR_PERMS=2775

directories=()
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do
    directories+=("$REPLY")
done < <(sudo /bin/find /Testdir/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 ! -perm ${EXAMPLE_DIR_OWNER} -or ! -group ${EXAMPLE_DIR_OWNER#:*} -or ! -user ${EXAMPLE_DIR_OWNER%*:} -print0)
```

When I run this script I get an error `/bin/find: invalid mode ‘testuser:testgroup’` which implies the subtring isn't working.

Thanks!

Comment: You want `%:*` and `#*:`

Comment: `-perm` takes either an octal mode (0644) or a symbolic mode (-g=w).

Comment: @piddl0r, as an aside, all-caps environment variables are [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) for variable names with meaning to the OS or shell, whereas lower-case names are reserved for application use. This applies to regular shell variables as well, since setting a shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable. Using lower-case names for your own variables thus means you aren't at risk for conflicting with new environment variables or builtins added in the future.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks bud! Good to get it right. Lots of find + replacing about to happen :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"${var%pattern}"` trims that pattern from the end, whereas `"${var#pattern}"` trims from the beginning. `${EXAMPLE_DIR_OWNER#:*}` is thus trimming a string starting with `:` from the beginning of your variable's contents, and will do nothing unless the first character in those contents is a `:`.

Thus:

```
-user "${EXAMPLE_DIR_OWNER%:*}"  # trim from last : to end of contents
-group "${EXAMPLE_DIR_OWNER#*:}" # trim from beginning to first :
```

See [the bash-hackers page on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) for more on the pertinent syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your `find` reads, in part:

```
 -perm ${EXAMPLE_DIR_OWNER}
```

Where `${EXAMPLE_DIR_OWNER}` has a value of `"testuser:testgroup"`. That is not a valid mode, which the error clearly states. You probably want:

```
 -perm ${EXAMPLE_DIR_PERMS}
```